# Why this java code always print "Unknown City" for any value input by the user?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, java.util.scanner, control-statements

This Java program is successfully compiled and run and accepting input from the user but **for every city value(Meerut, Noida, Agra), it is showing "Unknown City" Why??** Why it is always executing else condition?? I have used both sc.next() and sc.nextLine(), but in both cases i am getting the same output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JTP_If_Else_If_Ladder{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //String city="";
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter City Name\t:\t");
        //String city=sc.next();
        String city=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You Entered\t:\t"+city);
        if(city=="Meerut"){
            System.out.println("City is Meerut.");
        }
        else if(city=="Noida"){
            System.out.println("City is Noida.");
        }
        else if(city=="Agra"){
            System.out.println("City is Agra.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Unknown City");  
            /* for city=Meerut,Noida,Agra; why this "else block" always execute */
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: besides how to compare Strings, I assume you understand that System.out.println("City is " + city); is a whole lot less code to write?

Comment: You might also benefit from trimming your input (e.g. trailing spaces) & accepting lower-case input, too?